# How to implement a ChangeListener on a Java Object ( not java Componeni)

Tags: java, object, generics

It is mentioned in Oracle's Java Tutorials web site as, "A change listener is registered on an object — typically a component, but it could be another object, like a model — and the listener is notified when the object has changed".  So when I tried to implement a ChangeLsitener on my own Object, the error I got is, "The method addChangeListener(NewChangeListener) is undefined for the type Object"

High appreciation for your advice / corrections in advance.

My code is given below:

```
        package acs.engg.main.test;

        import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
        import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

        public class LayerCL {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                LayerTest l1 = new LayerTest();
                ((Object) l1).addChangeListener(new NewChangeListener());
                l1.setDD(15.);
            }
        }

        class NewChangeListener implements ChangeListener {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                LayerTest l1 = (LayerTest) e.getSource();
                if (l1.getDD() != l1.getDDOld()) {
                    System.out.println("A new value set in Layer Object is  " + l1.getDD());
                    l1.updateDDOld();
                }
            }
        }

        class LayerTest {

            double dd;
            double ddOld;

            public LayerTest() {
                dd = 0.; // default value
            };

            public LayerTest(double dd1) {
                ddOld = dd1;
                dd = dd1;
            }

            public void setDD(double dd1) {
                this.dd = dd1;
            }

            public double getDDOld() {
                return ddOld;
            }

            public double getDD() {
                return dd;
            }

            public void updateDDOld() {
                ddOld = dd;
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don’t see any attempt to implement changelistener support in your class. Why do you think, casting to a broader type will make new features appear in your class?

Comment: Great thanks, Holger.

Answer (score 0):

I could attain the solution by opting for PropertyChangeListener instead of ChangeListener because PropertyChangeListener can work for any javabean whereas ChangeListener can work on java components or component models where we have to define addChangeListener( changeListener object)  by ourselves.  The code snippet is given below:

```
        import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
        import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
        import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
        import java.io.Serializable;

        public class ProvenExampleofPropertyChangeListener{
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                LayerTest l1 = new LayerTest();
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    l1.setDD(Math.pow(10., i));
                }
            }
        }

        class LayerTest implements PropertyChangeListener, Serializable {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            double dd;
            double ddOld;

            private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

            public LayerTest() {
                dd = 0.; // default value
                pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
            };

            public LayerTest(double dd1) {
                ddOld = dd1;
                dd = dd1;
            }

            public void setDD(double dd1) {
                this.dd = dd1;
                pcs.firePropertyChange("dd", ddOld, dd);
            }

            public double getDDOld() {
                return ddOld;
            }

            public double getDD() {
                return dd;
            }

            public void updateDDOld() {
                ddOld = dd;
            }

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("dd      = " + evt.getPropertyName());
                System.out.println("Old Value = " + evt.getOldValue());
                System.out.println("New Value = " + evt.getNewValue());
                ddOld = dd;
            }


dd      = dd
Old Value = 0.0
New Value = 10.0
dd      = dd
Old Value = 10.0
New Value = 100.0
dd      = dd
Old Value = 100.0
New Value = 1000.0
dd      = dd
Old Value = 1000.0
New Value = 10000.0
```